# Understanding Ramanujan's approach in his proof of Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, logarithms, factorial

I've been reading through Ramanujan's proof of [Betrand's Postulate](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319233322/http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html) and I'm not clear why he didn't state his proof in terms of $\varphi(2x) - \varphi(x)$

What would be wrong with this approach for example:

Let $\varphi(x) = \sum_{p\le x}\log p$

Let $\psi(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1}\varphi(x^{\frac{1}{n}})$

$\psi(2x) - 2\psi(\sqrt{2x}) = \varphi(2x) - \varphi([2x]^\frac{1}{2}) + \varphi([2x]^{\frac{1}{3}}) - \ldots$

$\psi(2x) - 2\psi(\sqrt{2x}) \le \varphi(2x) \le \psi(2x)$

$\psi(2x) - \psi(x) \le \log[2x]! - 2\log[x]! \le \psi(2x) - \psi(x) + \psi(\frac{2}{3}x)$

$\psi(2x) - \psi(x) + \psi(\frac{2}{3}x) \le \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) + 2\psi(\sqrt{2x}) + \psi(\frac{2}{3}x)$

Using $\psi(x) < \frac{3}{2}x$, if $x > 0$ from (13) in the [proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319233322/http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html), we have:

$\log[2x]! - 2\log[x]! \le \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) + 3\sqrt{2x} + x$

Using [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_approximation), we have $2x! > \sqrt{4\pi{x}}(\frac{2x}{e})^{2x}$ and $\exists{w}$ so that $x! < \sqrt{w\pi{x}}(\frac{x}{e})^x$

If I did my calculations correctly: $\log[2x]! - 2\log[x]! > \frac{4}{3}x$ for $x \ge 48$

For $x > 162$, $\frac{1}{3}x - 3\sqrt{2x} > 0$

So for $x \ge 162$, we have:

$\varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) > 0$

edit: I've modified the argument to be closer to Ramanujan's proof based on Daniel's comment.  Before I used $\psi(2x) - \psi(x) \le \log[2x]! - \log[x]! \le \psi(2x) - \psi(x) + \psi(x)$ which may not be valid.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Ramanujan does his analysis using $\varphi(x) - \varphi(\frac{1}{2}x)$ and then uses the Gamma function to deal with the lower bound.  My thought is that his argument requires less steps if he uses $\varphi(2x) - \varphi(x)$ from the beginning.  As I understand it, he would then not need to use the Gamma function to establish the lower bound.  He could use Stirling's formula for factorials.

Comment: We have $\psi(2x)+\psi(2x/2)+\psi(2x/3)...-\psi(x)-\psi(x/2)-\psi(x/3)...$ So $\psi(2x)-\psi(x) < \psi(2x)$ and $\psi(2x/2)-\psi(x/2)< \psi(2x/2)...$ but the sum of these differences could exceed $\psi(2x)$?

Comment: Great point.  This may be the reason that Ramanujan took the approach that he did!  Ramanujan's proof stems from $\log[x]! - 2\log[\frac{1}{2}x]! \le \psi(x) - \psi(\frac{1}{2}x) + \psi(\frac{1}{3}x)$.  This may not hold for the approach that I used.  Let me investigate more.

Comment: +1. i didn't check the stirling approx but plotted the functions. if there's a mistake i don't see it. nice question either way.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{p\le x} \log p$ is more commonly (at least these days) denoted by $\theta(x)$ rather than $\varphi(x)$.